# Why does type conversion for [] and !![] return not the same result?

Tags: javascript

Why does type conversion for `[]` and `!![]` return not the same result?

```js
console.log([] == false); // true
console.log(!![] == false); // false
```

Comment: For the second output: an array (even empty) is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy). `![]` returns `false`. `!false` returns `true`.

Comment: For the first output: https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-11.9.3 or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Equality

Comment: `[] == false` is evaluated as `ToPrimitive([]) == ToNumber(false)` which is `0 == 0`.

Answer (score 3):

For the first output: https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-11.9.3

`[] == false` is evaluated as `ToPrimitive([]) == ToNumber(false)` which is `ToNumber([]) == ToNumber(false)` and finally `0 == 0`.

The conversion chain step by step:

We're starting with `[] == false`.

Step 1:

> 7. If Type(y) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison x == ToNumber(y).

Now, we have `[] == 0`.

Step 2:

> 9. If Type(x) is Object and Type(y) is either String or Number,
>    return the result of the comparison ToPrimitive(x) == y.

Some examples of this conversion chain:

```js
console.log(Number([]));
console.log(Number(false));
console.log([0] == false);
console.log(['0'] == false);
console.log([1] == true);
console.log(['1'] == true);
console.log(['0'] == 0);
console.log([1] == '1');
console.log([1,2,3] == '1,2,3');
```

For the second output: an array (even empty) is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy). `![]` returns false. `!false` returns `true`.

Some examples:

```js
console.log(Boolean([]));
console.log(![]);
console.log(!![]);
```